# Calculate average operating current

Tags: power, batteries, current

I have a device that has two operating modes. The energy consumption for the first mode is 200 mA and 50 mA for the second. The device spends 80% of the time on the first mode and 20% on the second one.

What is the formula to use for calculating the total average energy consumption ?
Is this equation correct ?

$$
I_{total} = I_{mode1} * 0.8 + I_{mode2} * 0.2 
$$

Thanks!

Comment: Sounds like homework. Is it?

Comment: Not a homework :) I have a sensor with two modes  and I am trying to figure out how long will it run with a 5100 mAh battery. I have tried to calculate how long each  stage will last, then multiply by the duty cycle of each mode. However I think my calculations are not correct since I don't get the same result using the operating time from the formula I gave.

Comment: Show your actual calculations then.

Comment: Using the formula above i get:

$$
I_{total} = 200 * 0.8 + 50 * 0.2 = 170 mA
$$

then to calculate how long the battery will last:
$$
Time_{total} = \frac{mAh}{Amps*1000} = \frac{5100}{0.17 * 1000} = 30 hours
$$

However, if I do the calculation for each stage separately i get:
$$
Time_{mode1} = \frac{5100}{200} = 25.5 hours
$$

and 
$$
Time_{mode2} = \frac{5100}{50} = 102 hours
$$

then I multiply each time by its corresponding duty cycle, I get:
$$
Time_{total} = Time_{mode1} * 0.8 + Time_{mode2} * 0.2 = 40.8 hours
$$

I am confused which is the right one

Comment: There is a battery factor missing, the battery cannot deliver 100% of its capacity and survive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question shows some confusion between current, energy and (the missing measurement) power.

- Current is the measure of charge passing a point in a second.
- Power is voltage × current. ***P = VI***.
- Energy is power × time. ***E = Pt***.

You haven't given your system voltage so we can't do any power or energy calculations but we can work with current and ampere-hours.

Your equation is mislabeled. It should be
$$ I_{average} = I_{mode1} \times 0.8 + I_{mode2} \times 0.2$$
So
$$ I_{average} = 200 \times 0.8 + 50 \times 0.2 = 170 \ \text{mA}$$

Run time = \$ \frac {capacity}{current} = \frac {5100}{170} = 30 \ \text{h} \$.

The battery ampere-hours is probably rated at 0.1C (510 mA) discharge rate. Since your discharge rate is 1/3 of that you may be able to achieve extended run time.

Comment: Thanks @Transistor! My system voltage is 3.7 V. However, when I try to calculate the run time for each mode separately and then multiply it by the duty cycle of each mode I get a different result: 
$$
Time_{mode1} = \frac{5100}{200} = 25.5 hours
$$

and 
$$
Time_{mode2} = \frac{5100}{50} = 102 hours
$$

then:
$$
Time_{average} = Time_{mode1} * 0.8 + Time_{mode2} * 0.2 = 40.8 hours
$$

Comment: \$ Time_{average} \$ has no useful meaning. You're not running it for 0.8 of 25.5 h + 0.2 of 102 h.

Comment: I get it! Thanks again!